# Tangential part

Tags: symbols, math-operators

What is the code for the symbol used to represent the tangential part of a vector? For the normal part, one can use `$v^{\perp}$`, but how about the tangent part?

Comment: How about `$V_\parallel$`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I wanted an adequate T, like \perp upside down.

Comment: The symbol you need is called `\top` (table 195 in the current version of the “Comprehensive List”). You can of course define a better name, say `\newcommand{\tang}{\top}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `\perp`, upside down, called here `\tang`, and it obeys math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine,scalerel}
\def\tang{\ThisStyle{\abovebaseline[0pt]{\scalebox{-1}{$\SavedStyle\perp$}}}}
\begin{document}
$\perp$ versus $\tang$\par
$V_\perp$ versus $V_{\tang}$\par
$\scriptstyle V_\perp$ versus $\scriptstyle V_{\tang}$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

As egreg points out, the symbol actually pre-exists as `\top`, but I didn't have my TeX references handy to find it at the time.

Comment: It looks perfect, but where can I get those packages?

Comment: @EduardoLonga `http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine` and `http://ctan.org/pkg/scalerel`.

Comment: Well, `$V_{\top}$` seems easier.

Comment: @egreg I figured it must exist, but no one spoke up at that hour, and I happen to be away from my TeX references, so I followed my instinct..."when in doubt, stack it out."