# Getting the right font typeface

Tags: fonts, typography

I was told that to achieve the same font that appears on the following screenshot, I had to use `\usepackage{lmodern}`. But IMHO it does not look the same:

> DESIRED:
>   [image]
>
> MINE:
>   [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mystring}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. 
Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum.}






\begin{document}
\StrBefore[90]{\mystring}{ }




\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial C_{ui}}{\partial b_{u}} = - \text{err}_{ui} + \lambda b_{u}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

> Last but not least, how can I get this T?

[image]

Comment: The upper screenshot sure looks like either Computer Modern or its clone, Latin Modern.

Comment: do you have an electronic version of the original?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The original pdf? I do. I did the research by looking for the font using adobe reader but it did not work.

Comment: @Mico It is upside down

Comment: the fonts menu in adobe reader will tell you the fonts or you can use the pdffonts and pdfinfo utilities.

Comment: @Delan - Try `\top` for the symbol that looks like a sans-serif "T". E.g., `$\mathbf{P}^\top$`.

Comment: @Mico Or `\tang`?

Comment: @Delan - I'm not familiar with `\tang`. Where or how is this macro defined?

Comment: @Mico  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331094/tangential-part

Comment: @Delan - Sure, if you prefer `\tang` over `\top`, go right ahead. Nobody on this site is going to stop you.

Comment: @Mico Nah, I will stick myself to your approach. Thx